# Getting Hourly(Every 3 Hours in a day) Forecast using NOAA (National Weather Service)

Tags: ios, weather, weather-api, noaa

I am getting weather forecast data for 12 hours Using NOAA Weather API The URL is:
**http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?textField1=40.714269&textField2=-74.005968&unit=2&FcstType=json** ,
Now i want to get Hourly forecast data every 3 hours.Does NOAA API provides this kind of forecast.If yes then what is URL for that.I don't want to use any other weather APIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Following url we can get hourly(3 hours)temperature forecast data from NOAA.

**http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?lat=38.99&lon=-77.01&product=time-series&begin=2014-08-09T00:00:00&end=2014-08-15T00:00:00&temp=temp**

Detail documentation of what kind of data API provides can be found here:**http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php**

And list on parameters that can be got on hourly basis can be found here:

**http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/docs/elementInputNames.php**